# XAML Designer show error in VIsual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

#### Introduction

I wanted to develop the UWP application further and for some reason I am not able to use the XAML designer functionally. Every feature is up to date.

Have opened Visual Studio 2019 and switched to XAML-Designer.

#### Problem

The XAML designer does not recognise objects of the classes that are responsible for the UI surface.

#### Screenshot

[image: Error in XAML Designer]

Answer (score 0):

Change `Run Configuration` to `x86` to `Debug` or `Release`